# How do I add parameters in Ninject to a resolved dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject

I am creating a `WPF` application using the MVVM model. As part of the program I am creating a `UserControl` that contains an `ItemsControl` of `UserControls` with their own ViewModels linked.

The Code looks like this;

```
List<IDataViewModel> viewModels = new List<IDataViewModel>();

foreach (var type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DataModel)))
{
    var tempVM = ViewModelLocator.Get<IDataViewModel>();
    tempVM.Type = type;
    viewModels.Add(tempVM);
}
```

Is there a way to short hand this or pass a parameter as part of the .Get<> call?

**Edit**

I have gone away to look at the Factory Pattern as suggested in the answers and have updated my code as follows:

Factory, Ninject-Module

```
public interface IViewModelFactory
{
    IDataViewModel CreateDataViewModel(DataType type);
}

public class ViewModelModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IDataViewModel>().To<DataViewModel>();
        Bind<IViewModelFactory>().ToFactory();
    }
}
```

And the code above becomes;

```
foreach (var type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DataModel)))
{
    viewModels.Add(viewModelFactory.CreateDataViewModel(type));
}
```

The first call to the `Factory` seems to work effectively and creates a new `ViewModel`, however consecutive calls fail (That is to say appear not to create new `ViewModels`), is there something I am missing? I couldn't find much online and what there is, is not clearly worded and contains grammatical errors. The page I got the most from says nothing about why this happens. Do I need to have in my factory multiple `IDataViewModels'?
Like so;

```
public interface IViewModelFactory
{
    IDataViewModel CreateDataViewModel1(AccountType type);
    IDataViewModel CreateDataViewModel2(AccountType type);
    IDataViewModel CreateDataViewModel3(AccountType type);
    IDataViewModel CreateDataViewModel4(AccountType type);
}
```

**Second Edit**

Ensure that when you are adding a variable to a `Factory` `Interface` `CreateDataViewModel(var Variable)` that you mirror this change in your actual view model constructors signature! Rooky mistake on my part!

Comment: Make sure that you bind your viewmodel in `InTransientScope()`.

Comment: I tried that at first without success so removed it, that is the

`Bind<IDataViewModel>().To<DataViewModel>().InTransientScope()`

Not the Factory?

Have just tested the change but the application still only functions with the first view model called.

Comment: A further thought it this, the `foreach` loop currently runs 4 times, if the call to `viewModelFactory.CreateDataViewModel()` is calling the same instance each time would this not mean that each of the 4 **View-Models** added would be the same - thus creating 4 `Views` that are identical? 

It seems to be that it creates 4 separate `ViewModels`, since the **UI** shows that there are 4 `DataItems` in the `viewModels` `List`, but that each instance beyond the first seems to be incorrectly initialised with the `type` as no data is shown in the View Control.

Comment: Fixed - see Edit! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters by constructor injection in this way:

```
var typeParam = new ConstructorArgument("type", type);
ViewModelLocator.Get<IDataViewModel>(typeParam);
```

But instead of using static service locator I would recommend to use strongly typed factory, then inject this factory again by constructor injection.

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki

Comment: This is spot on thank you, I have gone away to look at the Factory Pattern, and have implemented it in my code as my edited post shows, do you have any further insight on this? Thanks.